# Correct way to format input and output of TimeField in Django Rest Famework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

*models.py*

```
class DemoA(models.Model):
    my_time = models.TimeField()
```

*serializers.py*

```
class DemoASerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DemoA
        fields = ('my_time', )
```

By default, for `my_time` field, it gives the format as `10:30:00`, (`%H:%M:%S`). What is want is the serialized format as `10:30`, (`%H:%M`).

Is there any default way to specify format for such cases, like specifying `extra_kwargs` in serializer `Meta`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify how the field should format the data by specifying a [**`TimeField`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#timefield) (this is *not* the [**`TimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield) of the Django model):

```
class DemoASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    my_time = serializers.TimeField(format='%H:%M')

    class Meta:
        model = DemoA
        fields = ('my_time', )
```

or with [**`extra_kwargs`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments):

```
class DemoASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DemoA
        fields = ('my_time', )
        extra_kwargs = {'my_time': {'format': '%H:%M'}}
```

Comment: Yes. That worked perfectly. Still i was wondering if there is any way other than overwriting the field in serializer, like can we specify it in `extra_kwargs`?

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande: normally the edited solution should work as well.

Comment: Cool. Worked :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Setting the format on the serializer works, but it can be antipattern on scale, since you will need to add it to all your serializers across your entire application. DRF allows you to set it on your settings as the default format for your application. You show set it, and override the format on serializer only when needed.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   ... # your other stuff
   'TIME_INPUT_FORMATS': ('%H:%M', )
}
```